# proto3 grpc clients: can they all omit sending message fields?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-python

Given the following proto definition
Can all autogenerated grpc clients produced by google code generation omit sending fields in PagingInfo?

In the python client, I can omit sending that field by using code like:

```
request = SearchRequest(paging_info=dict(a=OptionalField(d='d', e='e')), query='blah')
```

grpc proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message OptionalField {
  string d = 1;
  string e = 2;
}

message PagingInfo {
  OptionalField a = 1;
  OptionalField b = 2;
  OptionalField c = 3;
}

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  PagingInfo paging_info = 2;
}

message SearchResponse {
  string a = 1;
}

service SearchService {
    rpc Search (SearchRequest) returns (SearchResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proto3, all elements are considered `optional` (in the proto2 sense), so yes: any compliant implementation should be able to send a message that omits that element.